# heroku doesnt show my views. RoR project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I am trying to upload a RoR project I am working on. So to make it more interesting I just changed the home page, instead of having the usual one. I deleted the public/index.html, created a static page controller and added a new home.html.erb file in my views folder. I also changed the config/routes file. It works fine on my localhost. then I run these

```
git add .
git commit -m "Added home page"
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku open
```

and for a homepage I get the usual RoR page instead of mine. What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you post up your routes.rb file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try deleting public/index.html as that is probably getting served before hitting the app.

Comment: Ok you were kinda right. I deleted the public file, but im on ubuntu, and it seems that i to delete it from the TRASH too!

Comment: you might need to do a git rm public/index.html before committing